# UOW - A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am trying following code, it has two parts, one is navigation via prism.
When navigation is allowed I am starting a deep load asynchronously but each time with a new context. In later code I would want to cancel pending navigations that are not finished this loading but the below code does not even work so cancellation is a matter for later ;-)

navigation logic : no problems here

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    int relatieId = (int)navigationContext.Parameters["RelatieId"];
    if (_relatie != null && _relatie.RelatieId == relatieId) return;

    loadRelatieAsync(relatieId);
}

public void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
{
    bool navigationAllowed = true;
    continuationCallback(navigationAllowed);
}
```

deep loading logic:

```
private async Task loadRelatieAsync(int relatieId)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {

            _unitOfWork = _UnitOfWorkFactory.createUnitOfWorkAsync();

            IEnumerable<Relatie> relaties = await getRelatieAsync(_unitOfWork, relatieId).ConfigureAwait(true);

            _relatieTypeTypes = await getRelatieTypeTypesAsync(_unitOfWork, relatieId).ConfigureAwait(true);
            _relatie = relaties.FirstOrDefault();

            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
        }).ConfigureAwait(true);

        processRelatie(_relatie);

        processRelatieTypes(_relatie, _relatieTypeTypes);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

}

private async Task<IEnumerable<Relatie>> getRelatieAsync(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork, int relatieId)
{

    IEnumerable<Relatie> relaties = null;
    try
    {
        IRepositoryAsync<Relatie> relatieRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<Relatie>();
        relaties = await relatieRepository
            .Query(r => r.RelatieId == relatieId)
            .Include(i => i.BegrafenisOndernemer)
            .SelectAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        IRepositoryAsync<Adres> adresRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<Adres>();
        //exception is thrown after executing following line
        var adressen = await adresRepository
            .Query(r => r.RelatieId == relatieId)
            .Include(i => i.AdresType)
            .SelectAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        _relatieTypeRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<RelatieType>();
        var relatieTypes = await _relatieTypeRepository
            .Query(r => r.RelatieId == relatieId)
            .SelectAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);//exception is shown here
        throw;
    }
    return relaties;
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<RelatieTypeType>> getRelatieTypeTypesAsync(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork, int relatieId)
{

    IEnumerable<RelatieTypeType> relatieTypeTypes = null;
    try
    {
        IRepositoryAsync<RelatieTypeType> relatieTypeTypeRepository =
            unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<RelatieTypeType>();

        relatieTypeTypes = await relatieTypeTypeRepository
            .Query()
            .SelectAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return relatieTypeTypes;
}
```

I keep getting exceptions as if I forgot to await, but this is never the case.
I also use configureawait(true) properly whenever I want continuation on the GUI thread. But I keep getting this error in the deeploading logic. The unit of work and repository classes also use the async await mechanism but also there I am awaiting properly.

A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

**Edit** (removed logger code to reduce the code size)

Comment: please note that createUnitOfWorkAsync() is not a asynchronous method. It just creates a class that supports the async await paradigm.

Comment: `createUnitOfWorkAsync` does create a *new* context, correct?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(true);` this is a first timer..

Comment: ConfigureAwait(true) is the default behavior and you don't need to add that.

Comment: Then for SO id recommend to strip out son unnecessary code to make it easier for people to find the relative part of your code to help you with (e.g. hard to find you problem between all those logging).

Comment: And then to finally get things started: Where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: @Stephen createunitofworkasync indeed creates a new context.

Comment: I know configureAwait(true) is default, but doing the call explicit documents the code. processRelatie for instance is creating datastructures that are used in binding operations and must be on the GUI thread.

Comment: Downvoting is for when the question does not show research effort. Clearly if you take a look at the final answer there was a bug which is not so easy to spot. I bet the downvoter did not see it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is this code :

```
_unitOfWork = _UnitOfWorkFactory.createUnitOfWorkAsync();

IEnumerable<Relatie> relaties = await getRelatieAsync(_unitOfWork, relatieId).ConfigureAwait(true);

_relatieTypeTypes = await getRelatieTypeTypesAsync(_unitOfWork, relatieId).ConfigureAwait(true);
_relatie = relaties.FirstOrDefault();

 _unitOfWork.Dispose();
```

the UnitOfWork is an instance variable, when the scenario starts a second time it is overwritten with a new instance. The already executing scenario then uses that new UnitOfWork instead of its own because it is overwritten. 
Not so easy to spot, but a simple race condition.
I found it by replacing all instance variables by local variables and then the problem disappeared.

Comment: When you say, "fixed this by replacing instanced variables with local," do you mean variables within a method and replacing them by variables created as fields in the instance class? Just curious for knowledge.

Comment: I mean the opposite, a local variable has scope of a method where it is declared, while an instance variable scope is as long as the instance of the object it contains lives.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I'm still learning. I think I need more understanding of using async/await programming because I'm doing it without fully knowing it and I'm running into the same issues as above. When I change back to straight synchronous, I don't have those issues anymore.

Comment: you saved my life !!

Answer (score 1):

*This is probably not the answer, but a general look over your code.*

Main purpose of async/await is, to keep the current Thread available. This helps not blocking the UI Thread and keeping your App responsive.

You are already making sure that your deep loading happens on a ThreadPool thread, because you are starting it entirely utilizing **Task.Run()**. You can probably get around most of your problems by using the default synchronous methods of EntityFramework in your loading mechanism.

In a first look, your code looks *fine* as of the async calls. Maybe your deep loading is triggered multiple times?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i am doing it this way because i want to be able to cancel the operation in a next increment using a cancellation token.
The method loadRelatieAsync is called multiple times and is running concurrently because there is no cancellation yet, but this should not matter because i am using a different context each time. It is created underneith the unitofwork creation.
You are right i am trying to unblock the GUI thread as much as possible but i also want to be able to cancel the pending navigation operation

Comment: You can still only check for cancellation requests between your operations, that will make no difference then.

Comment: Why don't you just check, if a loading operation was already started and return it's task, if it is already there? Also are you 100% sure about your context? Because it when ongoing transactions cause your error, that's most probably the problem.