# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe in web api

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> GetReceivepayment(string PaymentID)
{
        ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> detailcollection = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> invoicesandcreditsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> detail;//= new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> ReceivepaymentHeader;
        Dictionary<string, object> Receivepaymentlist;
        //string PaymentID = id;
        if (db == null)
            db = new BizSight_Sample_Product_CompanyContext();
        ReceivePayment _ReceivePaymentHeader = (from rec in db.ReceivePayment where rec.ReceivePaymentId == PaymentID.ToString() select rec).FirstOrDefault();
        Receivepaymentlist = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        ReceivepaymentHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

Comment: ReceivePayment _ReceivePaymentHeader = (from rec in db.ReceivePayment where rec.ReceivePaymentId == PaymentID.ToString() select rec).FirstOrDefault();    i getting error this line   .                                                                    
                   if you know can you please answer me How to solve above issue thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331244/keep-getting-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-asynch