# A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed with UnitofWork and async

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

**My unitofwork code**

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly CAMSDbEntities _context;
        private bool _disposed;
        public Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        private Guid _objectId;

        public UnitOfWork(IContextFactory contextFactory)
        {
            _context = contextFactory.DbContext as CAMSDbEntities;
            _objectId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public IGenericRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
        {
            if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)) == true)
            {
                return repositories[typeof(T)] as GenericRepository<T>;
            }
            GenericRepository<T> repo = new GenericRepository<T>(_context);
            repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
            return repo;
        }
```

**My unity config**

```
      container.RegisterType<IHttpContext, HttpContextObject>();
                container.RegisterType<IDataBaseManager, DataBaseManager>();
                container.RegisterType<IContextFactory, ContextFactory>();

                container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));

                container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

                container.RegisterType<IAnalytics, DashbordService>();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

**webApi Controller**

```
 public class DashbordController : ApiController
        {
            private static IAnalytics _analytics;
            public DashbordController(IAnalytics dashbordService)
            {
                _analytics = dashbordService;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetStudentAssessmentHistory")]
            public IHttpActionResult GetStudentAssessmentHistory(int studentID)
            {
                var result = _analytics.GetStudentAssessmentHistoryGraphData(studentID);
                return Ok(result);
            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetStudentFeePaymentHistory")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStudentFeePaymentData(int studentID)
            {
                var result = await _analytics.GetStudentFeePaymentData(studentID);
                return Ok(result);
            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetLedgerHitoryByDepartment")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLedgerHitoryByDepartment(int schoolID, int departmentId)
            {
                var result = await _analytics.GetLedgerHitory(schoolID, departmentId);
                return Ok(result);
            }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetLedgerExpenseTrendByDepartment")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLedgerExpenseTrendByDepartment(int schoolID)
            {
                var result = await _analytics.GetLedgerExpenseTrend(schoolID);
                return Ok(result);
            }
```

**dashboardservice Code**

```
  public async Task<List<LedgerExpense>> GetLedgerExpenseTrend(int schoolId)
        {
            try
            {
                var ledgerExpenses = new List<LedgerExpense>();
                var currentDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
                DateTime previoYearDate = currentDate.AddYears(-1);
                var ledgerPayments = await  _unitOfWork.Repository<LedgerDetail>().GetManyAsync(x => x.SchoolID == schoolId && x.PaymentDate <= currentDate
                                                       && x.PaymentDate >= previoYearDate);

                foreach (var ledgerPayment in ledgerPayments.OrderBy(x => x.PaymentDate).GroupBy(y => y.DepartmentID))
                {
                    var department = await  _unitOfWork.Repository<DeptartmentType>().GetAsync(x => x.ID == ledgerPayment.Key);

                    var ledgerData = new LedgerExpense
                    {
                        Department = department.DepartmentName,
                        TotalLedgerExpense = 0
                    };

                    foreach (var departmentPayment in ledgerPayment)
                    {
                        ledgerData.TotalLedgerExpense += departmentPayment.TotalPaidAmount;
                    }

                    ledgerExpenses.Add(ledgerData);
                }

                return ledgerExpenses;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Log("An error occurred while fetching ledger expenses");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I have similar type of asynchronous metods implemented in my dashboardservice code. whenever I request a dashboard UI all request comes to the same controller at the same time and creates the new object for unitofwork and dbcontext for each request one by one. it works perfectly sometimes but Sometimes I think unitofwork and dbcontext object flows with the wrong thread and throws this error. I think somehow its picking wrong dbcontext which is already busy with someother api request from dashboard service.

Comment: No using statements to dispose the unitofwork afterwards? Your error handling inside the dataservice is completely useless, you are not handling, you are ignoring errors, there is no need for error handling if you are not doing anything useful with it, you might as well let it go through to the client, it will be more meaningful than logging a string and ignoring potential errors...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UOW - A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331244/uow-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-asynchronous)

Comment: @Icepickle where exactly you want me to dispose of unitofwork ?I think all request inside controller will create a new unitofwork instance but still unitofwork and context shared between multiple instances of controller for each request.

Comment: You have so many methods in your code. Please narrow down the error to a specific method. If all of them produce the same error, just post one method so we dont have to read so much code. Also explain how the work flows--controller > we api > repo?

Comment: @MickyD  I don't see this issue as a duplicate as here unitofwork object created at constructor of each service request and it will provide a new instance for all API request at the dasborad controller but still picking a wrong thread to process the unitofwork and dbcontext

Comment: That makes zero difference

Comment: @CodingYoshi  yes all of them producing an error but it can vary each time. some works fine and some fails based on for which dbcontext thread is getting blocked. flow is like from UI I am requesting all controller methods at once which create a new instance for each request inside controller and indirectly create new objects for unitofwork/dbcontext and request a service code.   Controller>webapi>unitofwork>Service-(can fail at any service)

Comment: @MickyD worked fine after removing static keyword from the controller (private static IAnalytics _analytics;) Thanks CodingYoshi to understand the problem

Comment: You seem to cache repositories... Making it very hard to track who uses what where, why, when. And inviting this kind of error. Premature optimization is still the mother of all bugs.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can explain your thought by some example? I'm not able to understand where exactly I need to change in repositories

Comment: I reacted to the `repositories.Keys.Contains()` code. That is stuff you should leave to a DI container, or just use disposables.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the static keyword in your controller from this code:

```
private static IAnalytics _analytics;`
```

Once that has been created, it will never be created again unless the application pool is recycled (manual or IIS restart etc.) Since you are using the same instance for all requests, you are getting that error at random. If a request finishes before the next one arrives, it will *NOT* result in an error. Otherwise it will. Hence the reason for not always getting the error (as you mention in your question).

Please read about how `static` affects the design in a web scenario (or server).

Try and think of web requests as a single transaction, all classes are created for each request and then thrown away after the request has been served. That means if you have `static` or any other mechanism which is for sharing, it will be shared between requests.